# PHP: Ordering array by 2 values

Tags: php, arrays

Example array:

```
$ratings[] = array("8.25", "7", "john");
$ratings[] = array("8", "7", "kent");
$ratings[] = array("9", "7", "broman");
$ratings[] = array("9", "9", "yodude");
$ratings[] = array("10", "4", "anotherman");
```

I need to order this array by first value descending, then second value descending if the first value is equal.

The ordered array should look like this:

```
$ratings[] = array("10", "4", "anotherman");
$ratings[] = array("9", "9", "yodude");
$ratings[] = array("9", "7", "broman");
$ratings[] = array("8.25", "7", "john");
$ratings[] = array("8", "7", "kent");
```

How would you go about doing this? I'm guessing there is a better way to do it than to loop through it twice.

Comment: Please invest 5 min todo this yourself! Use google try somethings and you will get it yourself!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Comment: Rizier, there's multiple ways, I asked because I would like to know the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, `uasort` was the way to go.
This is how I solved it:

```
uasort($ratings, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a[0] == $b[0]) {
        if ($a[1] == $b[1]) {
            return 0;
        }
        return $a[1] > $b[1] ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Some would argue its better using `array_multisort()`